# Cannot get permission to read/write collection throughput using Cosmos DB role-based access control

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

We are using Core(SQL) Cosmos DB. Now we are trying to add a role and here are the requirements:

1. Read permission of all metrics.
2. Read and write permission of all settings, including database account level, database level and (container)collection level.
3. **No** read or write permission of documents.

We have added all the following permissions to the role. However, we are still unable to

1. Read and write throughput(scale) of collection
2. Write all kinds of account level settings
3. Read the throughput(number of requests) metric. But other metrics like storage, availability, latency, consistency are available.

Do we miss anything?

````
```"Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccountNames/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/cassandraKeyspaces/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/cassandraKeyspaces/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/cassandraKeyspaces/tables/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/cassandraKeyspaces/tables/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/cassandraKeyspaces/tables/throughputSettings/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/cassandraKeyspaces/tables/throughputSettings/write",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/cassandraKeyspaces/tables/write",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/cassandraKeyspaces/throughputSettings/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/changeResourceGroup/action",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/databases/collections/metricDefinitions/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/databases/collections/metrics/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/databases/collections/partitionKeyRangeId/metrics/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/databases/collections/partitions/metrics/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/databases/collections/partitions/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/databases/collections/partitions/usages/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/databases/metricDefinitions/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/databases/metrics/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/databases/usages/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/getBackupPolicy/action",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/gremlinDatabases/graphs/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/gremlinDatabases/graphs/throughputSettings/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/gremlinDatabases/graphs/throughputSettings/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/gremlinDatabases/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/gremlinDatabases/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/gremlinDatabases/throughputSettings/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/gremlinDatabases/throughputSettings/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/metricDefinitions/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/metrics/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections/throughputSettings/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/collections/throughputSettings/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/throughputSettings/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/mongodbDatabases/throughputSettings/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/percentile/metrics/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/percentile/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/percentile/sourceRegion/targetRegion/metrics/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/percentile/targetRegion/metrics/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/privateEndpointConnectionProxies/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/privateEndpointConnections/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/region/databases/collections/metrics/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/region/databases/collections/partitionKeyRangeId/metrics/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/region/databases/collections/partitions/metrics/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/region/databases/collections/partitions/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/region/metrics/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/restore/action",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/storedProcedures/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/throughputSettings/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/throughputSettings/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/triggers/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/userDefinedFunctions/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/containers/userDefinedFunctions/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/throughputSettings/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/sqlDatabases/throughputSettings/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/tables/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/tables/throughputSettings/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/tables/throughputSettings/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/databaseAccounts/usages/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/locations/operationsStatus/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/operationResults/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/operations/read",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/register/action",
  "Microsoft.DocumentDB/register/action",```
````

We also tries Cosmos DB Operator Role. Scale/Setting/Explore buttons even disappear with Operator Role.
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You do not need a custom role for this. Take a look at the Cosmos DB Operator Role which provides access to all management (control plane) data and operations except for keys to prevent access to data.

You can learn more here.

[Role-based access control in Azure Cosmos DB](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/role-based-access-control)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Operator role meets all the requirements except reading/writing collection level settings. With Operator role, we cannot see the Scale/Setting options. Added the screenshot in question description.